How to add total column in gt_summary stratified table
I am trying to create stratified summary table with 93 levels of stratification.
I used the below code
table0 <-  data1 %>%  select(A6_ULB_NAME, D6, D7, A8_TYPE_OF_HOUSE) %>% tbl_strata(strata = A6_ULB_NAME,.tbl_fun = ~ .x |> tbl_summary(by = A8_TYPE_OF_HOUSE, missing = "no") ) %>% add_overall()

But unfortunately, getting the below error
Error in UseMethod("add_overall") : no applicable method for 'add_overall' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_strata', 'tbl_merge', 'gtsummary')"

How to generate the stratified table with an overall column?

Please read about how to make a great R reproducible example and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. Also include your expected output.

Based on your error it seems you are not passing the right object to add_overall(). According to the documentation it expects one of: tbl_summary, tbl_svysummary, tbl_continuous, tbl_custom_summary.

Using add_overall you can add an overall column to tbl_summary. To add an overall column to a stratified table requires a different approach, e.g. create a separate unstratified summary table, then use tbl_merge to merge the stratified and unstratified tables.
Using the default example from gtsummary:
library(gtsummary)

dat <- trial |>
  select(age, grade, stage, trt) |>
  mutate(grade = paste("Grade", grade))

list(
  dat |>
    tbl_strata(
      strata = grade,
      .tbl_fun =
        ~ .x |>
        tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") |>
        add_overall(last = TRUE),
      .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
    ),
  dat |>
    select(-grade) |> 
    tbl_summary(
      by = trt, missing = "no"
    ) |> 
    add_overall(last = TRUE) |> 
    modify_spanning_header(
      all_stat_cols() ~ '**All Grades**, N = {N}'
    )
) |> 
  tbl_merge(tab_spanner = FALSE)


